# How can I type for Collection<? super Some>?

Tags: generics, java-8, covariance, invariants, pecs

I have a method look like this.

```
public void some(..., Collection<? super Some> collection) {
    // WOOT, PECS!!!
    final Stream<Some> stream = getStream();
    stream.collect(toCollection(() -> collection));
}
```

And how can I make this method returns given collection instance type-safely?

I tried this.

```
public <T extends Collection<? super Some>> T some(..., T collection) {
    final Stream<Some> stream = getStream();
    stream.collect(toCollection(() -> collection)); // error.
    return collection; // this is what I want to do
}
```

Comment: `.collect(toCollection(() -> collection))` violates the contract, as the supplier is supposed to return an empty new collection on each evaluation. There are a lot of scenarios where this can break. Just use `.forEachOrdered(collection::add)` instead. This should also fix your compile problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found I have to do this

```
public <T extends Collection<Some>> T some(..., T collection) {
    final Stream<Some> stream = getStream();
    stream.collect(toCollection(() -> collection));
    return collection; // this is what I want to do
}
```

So that I can do this

```
List<Some> list = some(..., new ArrayList<>();
```

I wish I can explain.

Comment: And what is the goal of pâssing the collection as parameter ? Like choose when call the method the type of collection you have List, Set, .. ?

Comment: If that’s your intended use case, just use `public <T extends Collection<Some>> T some(..., Supplier<T> s) { return getStream().collect(toCollection(s)); }`. Then, you can write `List<Some> list = some(..., ArrayList::new);`